# Link List Reverse Recursive Function Not Working

Tags: c, list, recursion, reverse, singly-linked-list

I'm unable to workout why my recursive function isn't working. Everytime I run the code the linked list doesn't print in reverse.

```
typedef struct numberline NUMBERLINE; 
NUMBERLINE * startptr;
NUMBERLINE * newptr;
NUMBERLINE * curptr;

NUMBERLINE *revRecursive(NUMBERLINE *curptr)
{

    NUMBERLINE *q, *head;

    if(curptr->next == NULL)
    {
        return curptr;
    }

    head = curptr;

    q = curptr = revRecursive(curptr);

    while(q->next != NULL)
    {
        q = q->next;
    q->next = head;
    head->next = NULL;

    return curptr;
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong pointer in the parameter, or I haven't implemented properly I'm unsure.

Comment: @mjwills oh whoops wrong tag

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). A quick [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be enough to find the problem (especially if you indent the code consistently).

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Post more info about the input being passed and the output of your program

Comment: Your rubber-duck debugging session should help you clarify for yourself the function's purpose, preconditions, and postconditions, including the significance of the arguments and return value.  Don't waste that: record those details in a documentation comment associated with the function, even if only for your own future benefit.

Comment: Your code doesn't include any means to print out anything

Answer (score 0):

The function can look the following way

```
NUMBERLINE * reverse( NUMBERLINE *head ) 
{ 
    if ( head && head->next ) 
    { 
        NUMBERLINE *current = head; 
        head = head->next; 
        head = reverse( head ); 
        current->next->next = current; 
        current->next = NULL; 
    }

    return head;
}
```

As for your function definition then even this statement

```
if(curptr->next == NULL)
{
    return curptr;
}
```

arises the undefined behavior when `curptr` is equal to `NULL`.